WinForm object causing calls to asynchronous methods to get stuck
.Net8 WinForms Project Main Function
async Task<string> LoadData()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");

    return response;
}

//var formStuck = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();//If This Code Uncomment,Application will be stuck

var httpResult = await LoadData();

Application.Run(new System.Windows.Forms.Form());

No Form object can be instantiated before the asynchronous method is called, otherwise it will get stuck.
But moving the code out of LoadData and removing the await keyword allows it to run.
var formStuck = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com").Result;

Application.Run(new System.Windows.Forms.Form());

Couldn't instantiating the Form object cause some kind of mechanism change in the current thread?


Couldn't instantiating the Form object cause some kind of mechanism change in the current thread?

Yes. As you observed, creating UI elements will install a Windows Forms SynchronizationContext. This context is used by await to resume execution after its operation has completed.
However, the Windows Forms SynchronizationContext (like all other UI contexts) require a UI thread running a message pump to be able to do things like run async method continuations. In Windows Forms, your message pump is Application.Run. So you really shouldn't use await before Run. Blocking (.Result) will only get you so far; if you have any awaits at all (even in other methods you call), it won't work properly.
Instead, you should design a splash screen, show that immediately (and synchronously), entering Application.Run as soon as possible when your application starts up. The splash screen can start your initialization (which can then naturally use async/await, since it's running after the Application.Run starts). When the initialization completes, close the splash screen and load your main screen.
The splash screen approach will work with async/await instead of against it, and will also provide a better experience for your users.

I find answer is SynchronizationContext.
Before new Form(),SynchronizationContext.Current is null
var formStuck = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();

Before new Form(),SynchronizationContext.Current Init
can use
SynchronizationContext.Current.Send or SynchronizationContext.Current.Post

You can also use ConfigureAwait(false)
